# TwoWay Binding doesn't update the IObservableVector

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

Hello fellow programmers,

i'm currently stuck because i can't figure out how these TwoWay bindings works. I have a SETTING class with an IObservableVector with IInspectables and a Page class with an IObservableVector with IInspectables, too. In the SETTING class the vector stores boxed winrt::hstring and the vector of the Page class stores SETTING classes.

I've tried to bind the hstrings to listviewitems and the listview to Pivotitems but the vector of the SETTING class wont get updated.
But when I bind one item of the vector to a textbox it works perfectly fine and updates the first textbox in the listview too.

```xml
<Pivot HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{x:Bind settings, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SETTING">
            <StackPanel>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind setting_values, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <StackPanel>
                                 <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBox>
                              </StackPanel>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                         <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                             <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                             <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
                         </Style>
                     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                 </ListView>
                 <TextBox Text="{Binding setting_values[0], Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

Does anyone have an idea what i did wrong and why one Twoway binding works and the other doesn't

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Does your IObservableVector implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface?The IObservableVector can only monitor the addition or removal of the data.The change of an item still needs to implement the "INotifyPropertyChanged" interface.

Comment: yes i did it in both classes

Comment: I'm confused about the content you edited.It doesn't seem to be related to what you described earlier.Can you show more details about your behaviour and provide a sample to us?

Comment: yeah im confused with it, too. i will delete it.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed sample for us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thank you @faywang for trying to help. It works now. I changed the IInspectable vector to a vector of SETTING class. Also I use x:Bind for all Bindings now. If you want to see my solution, I can put it up. But for now i don't need help anymore.

Comment: Glad you solved it.You can post your answer.That would be helpful for other communities who meet the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with this setup:

```
// SETTING.idl
runtimeclass SETTING : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    String description;
    String value;
}
```

```
//SETTING_VIEWMODEL.idl
import "SETTING.idl";

runtimeclass SETTINGS_VIEWMODEL
{
    Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<SETTING> settings_vector{ get; };
}
```

```
//SETTINGS_PAGE.idl
import "SETTINGS_VIEWMODEL.idl";

[default_interface]
runtimeclass SETTINGS_PAGE : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
{
    SETTINGS_PAGE();
    SETTING_VIEWMODEL settings{ get; };
}
```

Now you can bind the values with a TwoWay Binding:

```
//SETTINGS_PAGE.xaml
<Listview ItemsSource="{x:Bind settings.settings_vector, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SETTING">
            <Grid Height="40">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind description, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Text="{x:Bind value, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</Listview>
```